# Как удалить триггер на SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Создал триггер, который при появлении новой строки запускает bat-файл.
После его создания запросы к бд стали зависать и не выполняются. Пытаюсь отключить - выбивает ошибку

```
'Действие Изменить завершилось неудачно для объекта "Триггер" "Telegram".
```

**Дополнительные сведения**

```
При выполнении инструкции или пакета Transact-SQL возникло исключение.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Превышено время ожидания запроса на блокировку. (Microsoft SQL Server, ошибка: 1222)
```

Для моего случая по этой ошибке решений в гугле не нашел.
При попытке удалить триггер запросом

```
DROP TRIGGER Telegram
```

Идет выполнение запроса, которое не заканчивается.
Вот код самого триггера:

```
USE [Problem]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Telegram]    Script Date: 26.08.2020 21:40:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Telegram]
ON [dbo].[smsTelegram]
AFTER INSERT
AS EXEC xp_cmdshell 'd:\telegram.bat'
```

Пробовал удалить через ПКМ по имени триггера

```
'Действие Удалить завершилось неудачно для объекта "Триггер" "Telegram". (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

**Дополнительные сведения**

```
При выполнении инструкции или пакета Transact-SQL возникло исключение.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Превышено время ожидания запроса на блокировку. (Microsoft SQL Server, ошибка: 1222)
```

Как мне снести этот триггер и правильно создать новый, который не будет зависать?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было перезапустить службу SQL Server через Sql Server Configuration Manager. Триггер не срабатывал из-за того, что эта база является репликацией основной базы на сервере.